# How to fix react navigation displacing my component from top of screen?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo, react-navigation-stack

I am working on a react native application and am trying to understand how to deal with `react navigation` as it affects my styling. Essentially when I navigate to a page, `react navigation's` top arrow with header is displacing my components (I'd like to move my black header bar up and use react navigation's arrow ideally):

[image]

I have react navigation set up in the following manner:

**App.js**

```js
    const ProfileNavigator = createStackNavigator({
      //Profile: { screen: Profile},
      QR: { screen: GenerateQR },
      EditAccount: { screen: EditAccount }
    });

    const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
      tabs: bottomTabNavigator,
      profile: ProfileNavigator
    })

    const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

I have a header component I put together for styling that I use on top of each page:

**pageTemplate**

```js
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {Text,View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
    import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
    import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

    class PageTemplate extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <View
                    style={{
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                        height: 130,
                        alignSelf: 'stretch',
                        width: '100%'
                    }}>
                <View style={{backgroundColor: 'black', alignSelf: 'stretch',width: '100%'}} />

                    <View style=
                            {{position:'absolute',
                              marginTop: '16%',
                              marginLeft: '3%',
                              display: 'flex',
                              flexDirection: 'row',
                              flex:1
                              }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.navigate}>
                        <Ionicons  name="ios-arrow-dropleft" size={32} color="white" />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    <Text 
                    style={{
                        position: 'absolute',
                        marginTop: '15%',
                        marginLeft: '12%',
                        color: 'white', 
                        fontSize: 30}}
                        >
                             {this.props.title}
                    </Text>
                </View>


            );
        }
    }

    export default PageTemplate;
```

I have a tab called profile which navigates through a list item to get to an account edits page:

**Profile**

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
    import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
    import { List, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements'

    import GenerateQR from './generateQR';
    import PageTemplate from './smallComponents/pageTemplate';
    import pic from '../assets/bigRate.png'


    export default class Profile extends React.Component {

        render() {
          const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
          navigateBack=()=>{
            navigate('Queue')
          }


          return(
            <React.Fragment>

             <PageTemplate title={'Profile Settings'} navigate={navigateBack} />

              {/*<Image source={pic} />*/}
              {/**  Frst Section */}

              <View style={{
                      //backgroundColor:'blue'
                      }}>
                      <Text style={styles.section}>Account Information</Text>

              </View>
              <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={()=>{navigate('EditAccount')}}
                            style={{position: 'absolute',
                            marginTop:'32%',
                            flex:1,
                            flexDirection: 'row',
                            flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>

                  <View style={{
                                marginLeft:'5%',
                                flex:1,
                                flexDirection: 'row',
                                flexWrap: 'wrap',
                                justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                                //backgroundColor:'yellow',
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                //borderRadius:50,
                                //height:'60%'
                                }} >
                    <Ionicons style={{marginLeft:'20%'}}  name="ios-person" size={72} />
                  </View>

                  <View style={{paddingTop:50,
                                marginRight:'40%',

                                flex:2,
                                flexDirection: 'row',
                                flexWrap: 'wrap',
                                //backgroundColor: 'red'
                              }}
                                >
                    <Text>Sylvester Stallone</Text>
                    <Text>+1 646-897-0098</Text>
                    <Text>SlyLone@gmail.com</Text>
                  </View>


              </TouchableOpacity>

              {/**add line section */}
                     </React.Fragment>
          );
        }
      }

      const styles = StyleSheet.create({

        option : {
          //position: 'absolute',
          marginLeft:'7%',
          alignSelf: 'stretch',
          width: '100%',
          height: '15%',
          //flexWrap: 'wrap',
          justifyContent:'space-between',
          //padding:20 
        },
        section : {
          fontSize:20,
          marginLeft:'5%'
        }

      })


      /**
       * 
       * 
       * 

                      <View style={styles.option}>
                        <Ionicons  name="ios-gift" size={32} />
                        <TouchableHighlight>
                          <Text>Rewards</Text>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                      </View>




       * 
       */
```

Ideally it be nice to drop the arrow icon and move the header up keeping react-navigations arrow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the arrows, you can create your own headers.

**Example**

```js
class LogoTitle extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Image
        source={require('@expo/snack-static/react-native-logo.png')}
        style={{ width: 30, height: 30, alignSelf:"center" }}
      />
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    // headerTitle instead of title
    headerTitle: () => <LogoTitle />,
    headerLeft: () => (
      <Button
        onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
        title="back"
        color="#fff"
      />
    ),
  };
```

[image]